# Extjs 5 , Dynamic Grid Memory leak in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs

We are using Ext Js 5.1.1.451

We have a dynamic grid (paginated), which will be populated with 25 rows and around 230 columns (sometimes more).

Following are the characteristics of the grid:

1. It has 5 static columns (last two has combobox and text field - added as a editor)
2. It also has a checkboxModel and cellediting plugin. (Both of which has rules in beforeselect and beforeedit listeners to control editability)
3. Remaining 225 columns are dynamically calculated from the JSON response as follows.

   Originally we will get only arnd 115 columns and based on a flag I will decide whether to make that column editable.
   In case that particular column will be editable, I will divide that column as two (example: If the column name is cost, I will name it Base_cost(This will be a read-only field) and Adjustable_cost(This will be a editable field)).
   All the editable fields will be a text field, which will be attached to that cell by an editor.
4. When the grid loads for the first time, it will load the store, and data obtained will have, column header details and row data.
5. So, First I will form the columnhead with header details, like giving them editor, width, name, dataIndex etc.
6. Then I will do the transformation of the row data (basically to give individual dataIndex for the newly formed Base_cost and Adjustable_cost columns.)
7. Now I will do a grid.reconfigure(columnHeads);
8. On the Final step, I will load the transformed data to the same store : store.setData(Final transformed Data);

So Here is the problem I'm facing:

My customer requirement is to use only IE (we are using IE 11). When we load the grid, exactly after I do store.setData my browser memory goes from 260 MB to 1.1 GB and when I go to the next page on the grid, memory again jumps from 1.1 GB to 1.5 GB and stays there.

First page grid load takes 40 secs and on second page it takes > 2.5 minutes and 3rd page it take > 3 mins , you get the idea. Main problem is until the grid is loaded completely, the browser is going to a frozen state.

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post any of my code here due to my company's policies and I wasn't able to create fiddle for this situation either.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the memory consumption ???

P.S : This behaviour is seen only in IE , in firefox the process is quite fast and memory consumption is below 500 MB under all cases.

Comment: I had BIG problems with a grid with 40 columns taking 30 secs to render. Don't you think that 225 columns is like 150 columns too many?

Comment: @Alexander : My real problem is not the amount of time it is taking, but it is the amount of memory that is being consumed by the browser.

Comment: I know that creating multiple stores can cause a memory leak in extjs apps it is not solved yet even in extjs6 as far as I know